# scoring="roc_auc" on GridSearchCV for RF and DT

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Reading the scikit-learn documentation and looking for similar topics I couldn't figure out an answer.

Can I apply GridSearchCV having scoring="roc_auc" on Random Forest or Decision Trees without any drawback?

Thank you in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: It is possible. 
                                                                     However, the feature is only available to binary cases under the stated question. As explained by @AndreasMueller.